# Why can I not see my output dataset in PowerBI?

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

Hi I've tried to setup a stream analytic in azure that exports data into PowerBI. I've followed the following tutorial [Feed Power BI from Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-power-bi/#create-your-own-power-bi-adaptor-using-stream-analytics).

My input has been successfully set up and I received the notification to say that the I passed the connection test. The same can be said for my output. My Query is shown below it's pretty simple.

```
SELECT
    Category, count(*)
INTO
    [*outputname*] //the name here matches the name of my output
FROM
    [*inputname*] //the name here matches the name of my input 
GROUP BY 
    Category,
    TumblingWindow(Day, 1)
```

When running the Job I set the job to start at '07/07/2016 01:00:00 PM' expecting it to run my query against an aggregate version of the data below (as I set the tumble window to a day). It seems to run, and I don't get any errors just a notification that its successfully running. However when I check for the dataset in my PowerBI workspace, It hasn't been created. I can see no errors in the audit logs either.

[image: Data]

Comment: from my experience with stream analytics, the best way to start is to set the output to blob storage fist, making sure the query works fine, and the output is formatted correctly, and only than, connect it to the real output.

Comment: Ahh I figured out my mistake, it was a configration error, in my input Path Pattern. I was including the whole URI (https://...) instead of just the relative path from the container I had mentioned under the container field.

Answer (score 0):

One of the very common reasons which Power BI does not create dataset is because data returns nothing. It means Stream Analytics job cannot found your blob files due to invalid Path pattern. Look at the image below to see the Path pattern

- **donetappsqldb** is the application insight name
- **1181bb....ceee** is the instrumental key of the application insight with dash omitted.
- **Metrics** is one of data type the application insight captures.
- **2018-01-31** is the format of YYYY-MM-DD
- **07** is time with format HH

[image]

The Path pattern to let Stream Analytics to pull data is **dotnetappsqldb_1181bbf7f91645d0b438b0da36f44cee/Metrics/{date}/{time}** and the format of date time must be valid.

You can test query to see if any data return. If data returns dataset will be available in Power BI.